# How to replace taskbar stock icon browser with my own icon

Tags: css, html

I'm going create a simple test of `html` files. I want to insert my own icon at the taskbar windows.

i has insert on event new tab this is the code :

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

can somebody tell me what's the code? I'll apreciated if can give some example too.. thank's for advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly...

Windows **taskbar** icons are not the same as HTML icons that are displayed on your browser tabs.

If you want to assign a specific icon to a file or filetype, you need to do the following.

1. Generate a `.ico` file that is the image to be used as your icon in windows.
2. Right-click on your file, then click `Properties`.
3. Under the `Shortcut` tab, near the bottom of the window, you'll see a button that says `Change Icon`. Click this.
4. Navigate to your `.ico` icon file and click open
5. Profit.

If you mean how can you assign the icon to your browser tab....

1. Generate a `.ico` file that is the image to be used as your icon for the browser tab
2. Insert the following code in the `<head>` section of your HTML:
   `<link rel="icon" href="<relative filepath to your icon>"></link>`
3. Save your file, test, profit.

It is important to get the filepath correct! In the below example, if your icon was located in the images folder, while your index.HTMLwas located in the root, your filepath would like this **in your index.HTML file**

```
<link rel=icon" href="images/myIcon.ico"></link>
```

[image: Filepath thing]

Comment: yes I know.. have u made shortcut desktop using Chrome App? on generate the shortcut, the icon of the shortcut and bottom taskbar windows, looks same as icon at the web. on code <link rel="icon" ... >

Comment: Those are two very different things, you cannot have your website create a taskbar icon on the client OS upon load. That would require OS intervention that is not possible through a website; it poses a HUGE security risk to the client's system.

Comment: Also, it's important to note that Chrome is an installed application on an OS. Your website is not, and therefore will not override the Chrome taskbar icon, or any other browser for that matter.

Comment: so unfortunately for me.. :(  thank's for new experience at this days.. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in your head tag `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">` and the file favicon.ico (matches relative path) is a valid image it wil be loaded as the icon of the webpage.